# "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1140 Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5.8

Below is my query in and while running this, it is showing the above error:
$results = DB::statement("SELECT t_complain_mst.id as id, t_complain_mst.createddate as createddate, t_complain_mst.compno as compno, compname, compfname, agencyname, compsubject, status from ( select * , row_number() over (partition by compno order by mark_date) rn from  t_comp_mark_log ) t1, t_status, t_complain_mst, agency_table where rn = 1 AND t_status.statusid = t1.status_id AND t_complain_mst.compno = t1.compno AND t_complain_mst.agencyid = agency_table.agencyid AND (t_status.status = 'Closed' OR t_status.status='Rejected')

Comment: Format the code carefully. Add complete error message text.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.